# How to make Titanium (SDK) work?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

After an update to Titanium SDK 3.5.0 on MacBooks with Yosemite there occur several issues on all my developer machines, which prevents me from working on current projects:

**The issues**

1. "ti info" stops due to an exception in longjohn.js (see attached below)
2. "ti setup" stops with another exception while spawning a childProcess
3. Titanium Studio doesnt find my iOS SDK, although there is at least iOS SDK 8.1 installed and work perfectly in XCode (further information provided below)
4. After each start of Titanium Studio there occurs an error dialog stating "An internal error occured during Computing SDK Info, java.lang.NullPointerException", which seems to be related to the Issue under #3, which i mentioned above.
5. Because of the points mentioned above it is not possible to build any iOS Application with titanium

**The installed versions:**

- node: 0.12.0
- npm: 2.5.1
- Titanium CLI: 3.4.1.201410281727
- Titanium SDK version: 3.5.0.GA
- java: 1.8.0_25
- OSX: 10.10.2 (Yosemite)
- XCode: 6.1.1
- iOS SDK: 8.1

*The error messages*

**1. "ti info":** (in terminal)

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.4.1, Titanium SDK version 3.5.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

 |[ERROR] Failed to run command "info"
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:185
        throw e;
              ^
logger.log (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/logger.js:72:21),target.(anonymous function) [as error] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/common.js:45:21),CLI.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/cli.js:955:17),/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25,Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:24:16),CLI._fireHookCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:269:12),/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:248:10,/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13,async.eachSeries (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:130:20)
ha
```

**2. "ti setup"** (terminal)

```
> Where do you want to go? 1

 |[ERROR] TypeError: Incorrect value of args option

    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:952:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:984:38)
    at run (/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:47:14)
    at Object.detect (/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/jdk.js:71:3)
    at async.parallel.jdk (/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/android.js:71:13)
    at /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:524:25
    at /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:111:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at async.each (/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:110:9)
```

**3. Titanium Studio doesnt find any iOS SDK:**

I already executed:
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Then i enter "Titanium Studio -> Preferences -> Studio -> Platforms -> iOS". The setting for iOS SDK Home is empty and shows "Not specified".

But iOS SDK for 8.1 is already installed:
[image]

[image: Titanium Preferences for iOS SDK]

Some important messages from the Titanium Studio Log File:

```
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Computing SDK Info...".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.portal.processor.MobileSDKConfigurationHelper.getVersionInfo(MobileSDKConfigurationHelper.java:133)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.portal.processor.MobileSDKConfigurationProcessor.computeStatus(MobileSDKConfigurationProcessor.java:74)
    at com.aptana.configurations.processor.AbstractConfigurationProcessor.getStatus(AbstractConfigurationProcessor.java:154)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.portal.actionController.MobileSDKActionController$1.run(MobileSDKActionController.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)


!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Sending Analytics Ping ...".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.aptana.usage.internal.DefaultAnalyticsEventHandler.getAnalyticsLogger(DefaultAnalyticsEventHandler.java:207)
    at com.aptana.usage.internal.DefaultAnalyticsEventHandler.sendEventSync(DefaultAnalyticsEventHandler.java:241)
    at com.aptana.usage.internal.DefaultAnalyticsEventHandler$1.run(DefaultAnalyticsEventHandler.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)



!ENTRY com.aptana.core 4 1 2015-02-20 11:37:18.555
!MESSAGE sudo: a password is required

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.core 4 0 2015-02-20 11:38:17.801
!MESSAGE (Build 3.4.1.201410281727) [ERROR]  Unable to locate the CLI executable. Please restart Studio or use Help > Check for Titanium Updates to install Titanium CLI.
```

(Funny side effect: asking questions like this one in appcelerators developer forum will be rejected immediatly with the message "This data was not accepted because it was flagged as spam." (i tried it out in multiple variations))

What can i do know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny fact: Appcelerator Titanium isn't working with Node 0.12.

To solve all these issues with one step i only needed to switch back from Node 0.12 to Node 0.10.35.

Comment: Everytime I reopen Appcelerator Studio, it reinstalls Node 0.12.7

Answer (score 2):

Using the older version of Node (10.33) resolved the issue for me.

I used the node package manager to install "n" which allows you to switch versions (you'll need to run it as sudo):

```
npm install -g n
```

Then switch the version, also as sudo:

```
n 0.10.33
```

Answer (score 0):

(OS Yosemite)
If anyone else is having this issue, please check permissions to the following folder:

/Users/user.folder/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/

Make sure to apply permissions to all subfolders / files. I had a permissions issue on my machine, after re-installing titanium 2 times, downgrading node to all kinds of different versions, and following all instructions in various stacked overflow threads.